# nginx http caching with etags

Tags: php, nginx, http-caching

Nginx prepends a `W/` to the etag if gzip is turned on. Meaning it is a weak etag.
Is it okay to check for strong or weak etags with php using `substr()` - or am I missing something here ..... is there a better way to know if nginx is serving compressed content ?

I tried to check if gzip is enabled with curl_init to my own server but it did not work and was creating a loop.

```
$etag = md5($request->getMatchedRoute());
if($browserEtag = $request->getHeader('If-None-Match')){
        if(substr($browserEtag, 0, 2) === 'W/'){
            $prefixEtag = 'W/';
        }else{
            $prefixEtag = '';
        }

        if($browserEtag === $prefixEtag.$etag){
            $response->setStatus('304 Not Modified');
            // only send headers and exit
            $response->headerFlush();
        }
    }else{

        $response->addHeader('ETag', $etag);
        $response->addHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=6000');
        $response->setBody(file_get_contents($somefile));
        $response->flush(); 
    }
```

Comment: You could create a extra page for that check, then it shouldn't loop & maybe better look for the Content-Encoding header in the response than to check on a heuristic that migth get false if nginx changes their implementation or when you start to use weak and strong etags.

Comment: @flob  thank you .... you mean curl_init() to an extra page ?

Comment: Yes, to break the loop, to a page that doesn't make that call.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... got it working with a test page. Also I just found out that actually passing gzipped data to the server with `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')` results unsurprisingly in a strong etag. Another option would be to `explode(' " ', $etag)` where offset 1 would always be the md5 hash without quotes and validate against that.